# Is it possible to create routes dynamically in .NET 4?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, .net-4.0, routes

In our application we use the new .NET 4 routing system to route certain requests to other parts of the site. We are only allowed to publish our site code in late evenings which means we have to stay late at work to publish any code changes. We frequently have the need to create custom routes to support legacy links to old content and route them to the new content. These are often needed right away and as our routes are defined in compiled global.asax we reach an impasse when we need these live immediately but cannot do a code push.

Is there a way that we could define routes in some sort of configuration file and have the site read them in programmatically without restarting the application?

Comment: Not directly relevant to the question, but have you considered automated deployments with continuous integration? Those can help you get back to family time.

Comment: @Jordan We have a lot of things we consider for deployment improvements but I don't directly have any control over that. We are required to be here when we release to ensure nothing breaks on the live server. I would love for us to be on TeamCity and just make it automated but that's not my call. None of that solves the problem of needing to throw up a route on the fly though as they would still have to wait until the automated release.

Answer (score 1):

As change of configuration file requires restart of application (and even if would not, routes are registered only on startup, not on every request), I don't see reason why route registration (for start?) could not be in library "just for routing" (Routes.dll)?

I have been using MVCTurbine which supports auto dependency injection/service registration, and route registration. I use class like this for route registration:

```
public class RouteRegistrator : MvcTurbine.Routing.IRouteRegistrator
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Registers routes within <see cref="T:System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection"/> for the application.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="routes">The <see cref="T:System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection"/> from the <see cref="P:System.Web.Routing.RouteTable.Routes"/>.</param>
        public void Register(System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                new string[] { "MyNamespace.Controllers" }); // Parameter defaults
        }
    }
```

This class does not have to be part of webui project, but can be in separate dll. MVCTurbine automatically loads (and calls) all implementations of IRouteRegistrator and IServiceRegistrator which are in libraries in bin folder (not having to be referenced). And, as I know, there is nothing preventing you to add new routes by adding dll which contains new routes in implementation of IRouteRegistrator to bin folder of application. This way, you can add new routes "on the fly", without risking rest of application (new dll is easily removed if something unexpected happens).

If you can't or won't to use MVC Turbine, you can use this concept to "extract" route registration to external dll by passing routes collection from global.asax to dynamically loaded library, containing (only) class with method for route registration.

With this (MVCTurbine or not) as starting point, if needed, you can easily read xml or txt config file into foreach loop for common routes, but that method would be limited to simple routes as it is hard (complicated, but not impossible) to represent any more complicated route configuration in text.

Comment: Yeah I was kind of afraid of "As change of configuration file requires restart of application". Unfortunately that's the whole reason we can't push during the day, we are not allowed to restart the application. It is an internal site and employees use it to do their work. Restarting it often causes them grief. Thank you for your answer though, compiling our routes into a separate dll could be useful.

Comment: Not sure if it is even possible, but route registration on every request could cost you great deal of performance. Well, if you use mvc, session should not contain any data, and if you enabled cookie based authentication, shouldn't little restart be pretty harmless? :) 
Anyway, hope that you can send mail to "allstaff" noting that server restart will be at x o clock, please save your work...
I suppose that management needs to decide what is greater emergency - work in progress or new routes :S

Comment: Agreed, this is a hard line in the sand with pretty much no room for compromise. Unless somebody has a better answer then management will have to be made aware of this fact and they can decide what is more important to them. Thanks obrad.

Comment: You may want to look at this resource http://forums.asp.net/p/1526588/3684302.aspx
ali62b posted an answer suggesting a "catch-all" parameter, which you could maybe use if dynamic routes can be managed by one universal route (some area) to "master" controller and then redirected from there based on parameters, but this really depends on what is your scenario.

Comment: Interesting idea. I will explore this further.

Comment: Why do you think routes can't be added during run time?

Comment: I don't think, I wrote "Not sure if it is even possible", because I have not tried. Probably you can, as RouteTable.Routes has "Remove" method. However, if you do dynamic routing, you need to have "static" routes - standard ones from global.asax as you don't want to mess with removing/readding those, and a way of getting this collection at some point in time, and then adding route to collection. Way of getting routes is storing it into session at application startup, and then adding route in some controller action. It can be done, but probably not what framework makers intended to be done...